# Debugging issue with Python increment

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, python-3.x, parsing

I'm writing a program that parses a .txt file and grabs key/value pairs of user defined inputs. The logic of my code is pretty simple. It grabs a list of strings that the program should search for and stores the list of string in its appropriate variable. I have written a function field_extract that does the key/value pair.

My debugging issue is "currentJob = job_start.index(jobStart) + 1". Logically is should work fine but for some reason it doesn't.

Code Below

```
n2600RA1 = []
n2600RA2 = []
n2600RA3 = []
n2600RA4 = []
n2600RA5 = []
n2601CV4 = []
n2601IV4 = []
(etc)....

job_start = []
job_end = []
names = []
name = None
pk = []

for row in rows:
    name = row[1]
    fields = row[4].split(',')
    start = row[2]
    end = row[3]
    prim = row[0]

    if name == 'JOB - N2600RA1':
        n2600RA1.extend(fields)
        job_start.append(start)
        job_end.append(end)
        pk.append(prim)
        names.append(name)

    elif name == 'JOB - N2600RA2':
        n2600RA2.extend(fields)
        job_start.append(start)
        job_end.append(end)
        pk.append(prim)
        names.append(name)

        (etc)...


"""
DATABASE CONNECTION ENDED
"""

outFileName = "out3.txt"

# The regex pattern that is used to extract timestamp from file
# it will search for timestamps like this 2017-06-13-22.31.30.978293
dateRegEx = r"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+"
# Compile the pattern
regExPtrn = re.compile(dateRegEx)


# Extract the current job fields
def field_Extract(fileLines, fieldsArray, delimit):
    # Empty string in which we will append the
    # extracted fields
    matchStr = ""
    for line in fileLines:
        for field in fieldsArray:
            if line.startswith(field):
                key, value = line.split(delimit)
                matchStr += key.strip() + "\t\t : " + value.strip() + "\n"
    # Return the string hold the extracted fields
    # Each field is onn a separate line
    return matchStr


# Open input and output files
test_file = open(r'C:\Users\cqt7wny\Desktop\SAVERS_REPT_DT0712.txt', 'r+')
outFile = open(outFileName, 'w')

# Initialize used variables
currentJob = -1
currentJobData = []
startAppending = False
outFileStr = ""
for line in test_file:

    # Get the current job
    # We will loop over each job start and check if this start is
    # contained in the current line, if so, this line will be considered
    # the first line of the job
    for jobStart in job_start:
        if jobStart in line:
            # the used search function return the index of the first
            # match of the string. If the substring has more than one
            # occurance in the searchable string, only the index of
            # the first occurance will be returned
            currentJob = job_start.index(jobStart) + 1
            # Set the flag to start gathering job lines
            # for each job we will apped alll its lines to an empty
            # list, so we have all job lines separated
            startAppending = True

    # If job start found, gathar job lines
    if startAppending == True:
        currentJobData.append(line)

    # Set the correct job
    if currentJob == 1:
        job = n2600RA1
    elif currentJob == 2:
        job = n2600RA2
    elif currentJob == 3:
        job = n2600RA3
    elif currentJob == 4:
        job = n2600RA4
    elif currentJob == 5:
        job = n2600RA5
    elif currentJob == 6:
        job = n2601CV4
    elif currentJob == 7:
        job = n2601IV4
    elif currentJob == 8:
        job = n2601CV1
    #elif currentJob == 9:
     #   job = aTL10GV1
    elif currentJob == 9:
        job = n2601CW3
    else:
        currentJob = -1

    # Check job end
    # We will loop over each job end and check if this end is
    # contained in the current line, if so, this line will be considered
    # the last line of the job
    for jobEnd in job_end:
        # Check that this is a valid job and that the job ending
        # string is contained in the current line
        if (currentJob != -1) and (jobEnd in line):
            print(currentJob)
            # As a job end found, stop gathering lines
            startAppending = False
            # Get the time stamp
            # We search for it in the currnet line using the previously
            # compiled regex pattern
            txt = "".join(currentJobData)
            # Find all occurance of timestamps on the current job lines
            #timeStamp = regExPtrn.findall(txt)
            # Check that a timestamp found
            #if len(timeStamp) >= 1:
                # If there is more than one timestamp in the current
                # job lines, get only the first one
                #timeStamp = timeStamp[0]
            # Append the found output to the output string
            outFileStr += '########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########'
            outFileStr += "\n"
            outFileStr += "job# " + str(name[currentJob])
            outFileStr += "\n"
            #outFileStr += "Timestamp: " + timeStamp
            outFileStr += "\n"
            # Extract job fields values
            outFileStr += field_Extract(currentJobData, job, ':')
            # Erase completed job lines to be used with the next job
            currentJobData = []
            # Set job to invalid job
            currentJob = -1

# Write the output to output file
outFile.write(outFileStr)
# Close opened files
outFile.close()
test_file.close()
```

Debugging output below on currentjob.

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
6
8
6
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

Comment: Oh my god. Lists everywhere. I would use a dictionary of lists here.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a break:

```
for jobStart in job_start:
    if jobStart in line:
        currentJob = job_start.index(jobStart) + 1
        startAppending = True
        break  # <-- THIS!
```

You should strongly consider simplifying your code as well. It has a lot of unnecessary repeating code.

Consider storing your jobs in a dict instead to save yourself:
(The job names could be fetched from the db or in a text file as well)

```
jobs_names = [
    'n2600RA1', 'n2600RA2', 'n2600RA3', 'n2600RA4',
    'n2600RA5', 'n2601CV4', 'n2601IV4', 'n2601CV1',
    'aTL10GV1', 'bEL10GV1', 'cHL10GV1', 'cZL10GV1',
    'dEL10GV1', 'dKL10GV1', 'eSL10GV1', 'fIL10GV1',
    'fRL10GV1', 'gBL10GV1', 'hUL10GV1', 'iEL10GV1',
    'iTL10GV1', 'nLL10GV1', 'nOL10GV1', 'pLL10GV1',
    'pTL10GV1', 'sEL10GV1', 'n2601CW3',
]

jobs = {n: [] for n in jobs_names}
print(jobs)
```

Outputs:

```
{'n2600RA1': [], 'n2600RA2': [], 'n2600RA3': [], 'n2600RA4': [],
 'n2600RA5': [], 'n2601CV4': [], 'n2601IV4': [], 'n2601CV1': [],
 'aTL10GV1': [], 'bEL10GV1': [], 'cHL10GV1': [], 'cZL10GV1': [], 
 'dEL10GV1': [], 'dKL10GV1': [], 'eSL10GV1': [], 'fIL10GV1': [], 
 'fRL10GV1': [], 'gBL10GV1': [], 'hUL10GV1': [], 'iEL10GV1': [], 
 'iTL10GV1': [], 'nLL10GV1': [], 'nOL10GV1': [], 'pLL10GV1': [],
 'pTL10GV1': [], 'sEL10GV1': [], 'n2601CW3': []}
```

Comment: But it was a valid bug?

Comment: I think your main problem is that you need to clean up the code. It is way to complicated right now.

Comment: @iNeed2LearnToEat: a response of "that did not work" is not really helpful to someone who is trying to help you. It is very good at this point to be as substantive and detailed as you can, otherwise your helper has no new information to go on. _How_ did it not work? What _did_ it do?